# Flask Git Enoent Spawn Error

Tags: python, git, heroku, flask

I'm trying to deploy a flask application to Heroku. I'm following the steps on the website to deploy my app using the heroku toolbelt. I'm able to execute the command

```
git init
```

but when I try to use

```
heroku git:remote -a bcamarketplace
```

I get the following error:

```
 !    ENOENT: spawn git ENOENT
```

There is no further description and I'm lost on how to resolve this issue. Anyone have some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you haven't added a git remote for the app.  Try running this:

```
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:your-app-name-here.git
```

Then proceed as you were.